# How do I list current files in a document library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a document library that I would like to get the list of file names and put them into a string[] array.  Can someone give me some sample code of how this would look like?

Comment: you will need to be a bit more descriptive please. Maybe show some code as well please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need server side object model (for a WebPart or a statndalone tool to run on the server). Please look at the SPDocumentLibrary class that has sample listing names 
of the items in a document library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdocumentlibrary.aspx.